# selection.toString() returns empty string despite of a selected range

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I am trying to select an element's text on click using the following code:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(element);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

Although the text is getting highlighted, empty string is copied to the clipboard on using Ctrl + C. Checking for selection.toString() returns an empty string too. Any idea why can this be happening?

Comment: I know little about ranges but try replacing `range.selectNodeContents(element);` with `range.selectNode(element);`
I recreated your error and this fixed it for me. example: https://jsfiddle.net/ShawnGrav/rd5rvu52/

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I took a look at your code and tried:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var selectionText = selection.anchorNode.textContent
```

and I got the selected text content.

EDIT: it appears this was wrapped in a click function...one second.

```
$('<your selector goes here>').click(function(e) {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(e.target);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  console.dir(selection.anchorNode.textContent);
  //text content should display...
  //now that the content is highlighted, you can copy it
  document.execCommand('copy');

})
```

Comment: `selection.anchorNode.textContent` is not the same as `selection.toString()`